How to Include Table Data in Examples Section for SpecFlow Scenario Outline?
I'm working with SpecFlow and have the following scenario outline:
Scenario Outline: Check Response
    Given I logon with User '<User>'
    Then the return code is '<StatusCode>'
    And the response contains accounts with the following data:

        | UserName | Address | Id     | Type    |
        | Test1    | 1.1.1.1 | 34533  | Windows |
        | Test2    | 2.2.2.2 | 74343  | Windows |
        | Test3    | 3.3.3.3 | 743223 | Windows |
        | Test4    | 4.4.4.4 | 345674 | Windows |

Examples:
    | User      | StatusCode |
    | User1 | 200        |

I want to add another test case with a different set of table data. However, I need to write another scenario if I want to verify a different table value, which duplicates a lot of code.
Is there a way to include the table data (like UserName, Address, Id, Type) directly in the Examples section so that each row in the Examples table can verify different table values without writing a new scenario?
Any suggestions or best practices on how to structure this in SpecFlow?
